# Barra de progresso não atualiza com download ftp

Tags: c#, wpf, ftp, progress-bar, webclient

Olá, então é o seguinte
eu tenho uma função que faz o download do ficheiro desejado a partir do http, e à medida que ele vai descarregando, vai atualizando a barra de progresso (sendo aumentado de 0% pouco a pouco até 100% quando terminado).

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\...\Img");
// Creates a webclient
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
// Uses the Event Handler to check whether the download is complete
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
// Uses the Event Handler to check for progress made
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressChanged);
// Defines the URL and destination directory for the downloaded file
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://link.../google2.0.0.jpg"), @"C:\...\Img\google2.0.0.jpg");
```

Mas eu precisava que fizesse downloads a partir do ftp e quando eu adiciono as seguintes linhas, ele não atualiza a barra de progresso à medida que vai fazendo o download, sendo só atualizada quando acaba (muda do 0% para 100%)

```
webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ftpUserID , ftpUserPassword);
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("ftp://x.x.x.x@x.x.x.x.com/.../file.extension"), @"C:\...\Img\file.extension");
```

Se alguém souber como ajudar a resolver, agradecia.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A barra de progresso não atualiza porque o total de bytes de um ficheiro descarregado por ftp é lido como -1 pelo sistema..
Tem-se que ler o total do tamanho e colocar na fórmula para obter a percentagem

[edit]
Esqueci-me de marcar esta resposta como a solução.
Ao ler o tamanho total do ficheiro então já é possível atualizar a barra de progresso corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void startDownload()
        {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
            
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://github.com/JPPlaysGamer/IndustriesExes.Inc/releases/download/ieip-pre2/IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip"), temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip");

                

        }
        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
                double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
                double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
                Mbs.Text = (bytesIn / 1024 / 1024).ToString("F2") + " / " + (totalBytes / 1024/ 1024).ToString("F2") + " Mb";
                Complete.Text = "Status: Downloading...";
                IEIPProgress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
                this.Text = "IEIP Installer - " + IEIPProgress.Value + "%";
                
            });
        }
        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                if(File.Exists(temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip"))
                {
                    File.Move(temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip",  localProg + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip");
                }
                
                Complete.Text = "Status: Completed";
                
                btnNo.Text = "Exit";
                btnNo.Enabled = true;
                
            });
}
```

Veja esse código sobre o DownloadFileAsync. Como esse método não bloqueia thread principal você pode cria dois eventos citados acima.

Para fazer essa porcentagem, primeiro deve criar uma variável para receber os bytes recebidos, tamanho total do arquivo, e para a porcentagem

```
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
                double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
                double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
                Mbs.Text = (bytesIn / 1024 / 1024).ToString("F2") + " / " + (totalBytes / 1024/ 1024).ToString("F2") + " Mb";
                Complete.Text = "Status: Downloading...";
                IEIPProgress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
                this.Text = "IEIP Installer - " + IEIPProgress.Value + "%";

            });
        }
```

Como esse exemplo é de um arquivo meu ele é de muitos MB então eu faço uma divisão de bytes recebidos por 1024, o tamanho de KB, MB, GB , ...

Eu faço duas vezes pois quero mostrar um megabyte mas se seu item for de kilobyte apenas uma vez. Depois faça bytes recebidos dividido por total de bytes vezes 100, na hora de adicionar esse valor para a progressbar use Math.Truncate(porcentagem). Use o toString para fazer seu decimal formatado. Exemplo: toString("F2"), isso indica que terá duas casas decimais.

Em seu form (ou console), faça seu design que você mais gosta e preferir. Por fim crie um evento se o download foi completo:

```
void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                if(File.Exists(temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip"))
                {
                    File.Move(temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip",  localProg + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip");
                }

                Complete.Text = "Status: Completed";

                btnNo.Text = "Exit";
                btnNo.Enabled = true;

            });
}
```

Se seu download foi com êxito crie um if para verificar se o arquivo tem os bytes iguais ao que está na URL. Se não tiver esse tamanho crie uma mensagem de erro. Faça um bom controle de arquivos ou melhor crie uma temp.